# RT patch implementation

Tags: linux-kernel, preempt-rt

CAN communication not working after enabling `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT`.

We are presently using the RTC PCF85263A with an iMX6ULL processor, running Linux v5.15.52 on Yocto 4.0.

Additionally, I have added this RT-Patch to my Linux kernel even though it is not the same version as my Linux kernel:

https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.15/older/patch-5.15.55-rt48.patch.gz

Additionally, I have enabled the `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT` in the kernel. Before enabling this, every interface was working perfectly. However, after enabling it, I can't send or receive CAN data. Is there anything I need to change or am I missing out on something?